# Facebook auth with firebase get User data

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to use Firebase authentication with Facebook.

I have successfully implemented the login part and stuck while getting the user details from facebook using accessToken.

Here is the code:

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile"    );
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.e("FBRESPONSE",me.toString());
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                } else {
                                    if (me.has("picture")) {
                                        try {
                                            f_photo = me.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    f_email = me.optString("email");
                                    String id = me.optString("id");
                                    f_name=me.optString("first_name")+" "+me.optString("last_name");;
                                    handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                                }
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
            }
        });
```

This is the JSON response i get when called this.

```
E/FBRESPONSE: {"name":"Vishnu Reddy","id":"855235691328214"}
```

How do i get email, profile picture URL?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph). You need to have your user signed in and call the `AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync();` and initiate a request to the user data-fields you need.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But how to get the profile picture URL?

Comment: @mavillavishnuvardhan `https://graph.facebook.com/{userFacebookID}/picture?type=large`